# LibSSH: Interacting with a script/bash within a session

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ssh, libssh

I am using libssh APIs for communicating with a device. I am able to login as 'root' and run basic commands like "ls -l".

Problem statement:
I want to run a script within the file directory of this device (which I can) and then run a command once this script runs (which has it's own interface).

```
//create a new session
ssh_session mi = ssh_new();
if(mi == NULL)
{
    return -1;
}

//set the options
ssh_options_set(mi, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "10.10.10.10");
ssh_options_set(mi, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
ssh_options_set(mi, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "root");
ssh_options_set(mi, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);

//connect via ssh
rc = ssh_connect(mi);
if(rc != SSH_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to device: %s\n",
        ssh_get_error(mi));
    ssh_free(mi);
    return 0;
}

rc = ssh_userauth_password(mi, NULL, "pass1234!");
if (rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error authenticating with password: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(mi));
    ssh_disconnect(mi);
    ssh_free(mi);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Now I navigate to the script and run it:

```
    rc = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "cd /sysro/bin; ./mtce-term; logout device");
if(rc != SSH_OK)
{
    ssh_channel_close(channel);
    ssh_channel_free(channel);
    return rc;
}
```

Once ./mtce-term is run, a pop up expects some input (which I give but is not read)

> ->maintenance terminal connected... enter command

This is a blind spot for my code as it can not interact with this terminal. Any clues how to parse the last command?

Comment: Are you saying that the `mtce-term` program is causing this "enter command" prompt, and the "logout device" text is supposed to be a command in response to the prompt?

Comment: @Kenster -> Yes, that's correct